# Пытаюсь скомпилировать расширение php, в чем ошибка?

Tags: php

Устанавливаю php КриптоПро CSP

Дошел до шага генерации расширения

> В файле /opt/cprocsp/src/phpcades/Makefile.unix указать путь к
>   исходным текстам нужной версии PHP в переменной PHPDIR.
>
> Для сборки расширения в папке /opt/cprocsp/src/phpcades в зависимости
>   от разрядности системы выполнить:

```
  eval `/opt/cprocsp/src/doxygen/CSP/../setenv.sh --64`; make -f Makefile.unix
```

получаю вот такую ошибку

```
No compiler specified... trying to guess
g++ found in the path
g++  -DLINUX  -DUNIX -DHAVE_LIMITS_H   -DHAVE_STDINT_H -I/opt/cprocsp/include/ -I/opt/cprocsp/include/cpcsp -I/opt/cprocsp/include/pki -I/opt/cprocsp/include/pki/atl -I/opt/cprocsp/include/pki/cppcades -I/opt/cprocsp/include/pki/cplib -I/usr/bin/php -I/usr/bin/php/main -I/usr/bin/php/Zend -I/usr/bin/php/TSRM  -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -fPIC -DPIC -c -o PHPCadesCPSigners.o PHPCadesCPSigners.cpp
cc1plus: warning: /usr/bin/php: not a directory [enabled by default]
cc1plus: error: /usr/bin/php/main: Это не каталог
cc1plus: error: /usr/bin/php/Zend: Это не каталог
cc1plus: error: /usr/bin/php/TSRM: Это не каталог
```

там просили указать путь до исходников php
я указал /usr/bin/php, похоже это не то что ему нужно.

у меня ubuntu 14 64. Не могу понять где у меня исходники php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В  `/usr/bin/php` у вас скомпилированный php. Исходные тексты php - это написанный на С код собственно PHP, который вам и нужно скачать.

Comment: Да это помогло, но появилась другая ошибка. 
/opt/php-5.5.38/Zend/zend.h:51:26: fatal error: zend_config.h: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: Секунда в гугле https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&m=78828#post78828